# Living in the EU, working remotely for an Australian company

Tags: eu, working, self-employment

I am currently working for an Australian company, remotely from South Africa. I can move to the EU using my UK passport and possibly still work for this Australian company.

This company does not have a registered office in Europe.

Other than not being able to contribute to a state pension, are there any other issues to consider?

I take it I will be considered self-employed in the EU (I am considering the Netherlands and Germany) and be taxed on that basis?